# Ошибка React Native ( api.reanimated.nodes.NoopNode cannot be cast to api.reanimated.nodes.ClockNode )

Tags: reactjs, react-native

подскажите пожалуйста из за чего возникает данная ошибка.
Код, где выдает ошибку

```
    import React from "react";
// import native component
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    FlatList,
    Platform,
    StatusBar
} from "react-native";
//icon
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
//Colors
import { COLORS } from "../../../constans";
//Search Item Component
import SearchItem from "./SearchItem";
import Animated, { EasingNode } from "react-native-reanimated";
import { TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
const { Value } = Animated;
// Calculate window size
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //state
        this.state = {
            isFocused: false,
            keyword: '',
            productsFilter: ''
        }
        //---
        this.textInput = React.createRef();
        //---
        //animated values
        this._input_box_translate_x = new Value(width);
        this._back_button_opacity = new Value(0);
        this._content_translate_y = new Value(height);
        this._content_opacity = new Value(0);
    }

    // Function Search
    searchFilterFunction = ( searchText ) => {
        const data = this.props.products.filter((product) =>
            product.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
         );
         this.setState({ keyword: searchText, productsFilter: data });
      };

    _onFocus = () => {
        // update state
        this.setState({ isFocused: true });        
        // animation config
        // input box
        const input_box_translate_x_config = {
            duration: 200,
            toValue: 0,
            easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease)
          }; 
                   
          const back_button_opacity_config = {
            duration: 200,
            toValue: 1,
            easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease)
          };
         // content
          const content_translate_y_config = {
            duration: 0,
            toValue: 0,
            easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease)
          };
          const content_opacity_config = {
            duration: 200,
            toValue: 1,
            easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease)
          };

          // run animation
          Animated.timing(this._input_box_translate_x, input_box_translate_x_config).start();
          Animated.timing(this._back_button_opacity, back_button_opacity_config).start();
          Animated.timing(this._content_translate_y, content_translate_y_config).start();
          Animated.timing(this._content_opacity, content_opacity_config).start();
          // force focus
         // this.refs.textInput.focus();
         this.textInput.current?.focus();
    }
    
    _onBlur = () => {
        // update state
        this.setState({ isFocused: false });
        // animation config
        // input box        
        const input_box_translate_x_config = {
          duration: 50,
          toValue: width,
          easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease),
        };
        
        const back_button_opacity_config = {
          duration: 50,
          toValue: 0,
          easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease),
        };
        
        // content
        const content_translate_y_config = {
          duration: 0,
          toValue: height,
          easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease),
        };
        
        const content_opacity_config = {
          duration: 200,
          toValue: 0,
          easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease),
        };
        // run animation
        Animated.timing(this._input_box_translate_x, input_box_translate_x_config).start();
        Animated.timing(this._back_button_opacity, back_button_opacity_config).start();
        Animated.timing(this._content_translate_y, content_translate_y_config).start();
        Animated.timing(this._content_opacity, content_opacity_config).start();
        // force blur
        //this.refs.textInput.blur();
        this.textInput.current.blur();
      }; 
      
    render() {
        
        const scrollY = this.props.scrollPoint;
        const headerPlatform = 50;
        const clampedScrollY = scrollY.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
        });
        const _diff_clamp_scroll_y = Animated.diffClamp(
          clampedScrollY,
          0,
          headerPlatform,
        );
        const _header_translate_y = Animated.interpolateNode(_diff_clamp_scroll_y, {
          inputRange: [0, headerPlatform],
          outputRange: [0, -headerPlatform],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        });
        const _header_opacity = Animated.interpolateNode(_diff_clamp_scroll_y, {
          inputRange: [0, headerPlatform],
          outputRange: [1, 0],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        });

        return (
             <>
                <SafeAreaView style={{ ...styles.header_safe_area, ...this.props.style }} >
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[
                            styles.header,
                            {
                                transform: [{translateY: _header_translate_y}],
                                opacity: _header_opacity,
                            },
                        ]}                        
                    >
                        <View style={styles.header_inner}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('toggleDrawer')/*this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()*/}>
                                <Ionicons 
                                    name="ios-menu"
                                    size={30}
                                    color={COLORS.lighter_green}
                                />                                
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <View>
                                <Image 
                                    source={require('../../../assets/images/logo.png')}
                                    style={{
                                        width: height < 668 ? 180 : 170,
                                        resizeMode: 'contain'
                                    }}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                activeOpacity={1}
                                underlayColor={'#ccd0d5'}
                                onPress={this._onFocus}
                                style={styles.search_icon_box}
                            >
                                <Ionicons name='ios-search' size={20} color={COLORS.black} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Animated.View
                                style={[styles.input_box, {transform: [{ translateX: this._input_box_translate_x }] } ]}
                            >
                                <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this._back_button_opacity }}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        activeOpacity={1}
                                        underlayColor={'#ccd0d5'}
                                        onPress={this._onBlur}
                                        style={styles.back_icon_box}
                                    >
                                        <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={25} color={COLORS.light_green} />          
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </Animated.View>
                                <TextInput 
                                    //ref="textInput"
                                    ref={this.textInput}
                                    placeholder="Поиск товара"
                                    clearButtonMode='always'
                                    value={this.state.keyword}
                                    onChangeText={(value) => this.searchFilterFunction(value)}
                                    style={styles.input}
                                />
                            </Animated.View>
                        </View>               
                    </Animated.View>
                </SafeAreaView>
                <Animated.View
                    style={[
                        styles.content,
                       { /*opacity: this._content_opacity, */transform: [{ translateY: height/*this._content_translate_y*/ }] }
                    ]}
                >
                    <View style={styles.content_safe_area}>
                        {this.state.keyword === '' ? (
                            <View style={styles.image_placeholder_container}>
                                <Image 
                                    source={require('../../../assets/images/logo1.png')}
                                    style={styles.image_placeholder}
                                />
                                <Text style={styles.image_placeholder_text} >
                                    Введите ключевое слово...
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        ) : (
                            <View
                                style={{
                                    marginHorizontal: 20,
                                    marginTop:
                                    Platform.OS === 'android' ? 0 : height < 668 ? 0 : 60,
                                }}
                            > 
                              {this.state.productsFilter.length === 0 ? (
                                <Text style={styles.image_placeholder_text}>Товары не найдены</Text>
                              ) : (
                                <FlatList 
                                  data={this.state.productsFilter}
                                  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                                  renderItem={ ({ item }) => {
                                    return (
                                      <SearchItem 
                                          item={item}
                                          navigation={this.props.navigation}
                                      />
                                    );
                                  }}
                                />
                              )}
                            </View>
                        )}
                    </View>
                </Animated.View>
            </>        
        )          
      }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header_safe_area: {
        zIndex: 1000,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
      },
      header: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
        width,
        height: 50,
        top:
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? StatusBar.currentHeight
            : height > 736
            ? 40
            : 20,
      },
      header_inner: {
        flex: 1,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
      },
      search_icon_box: {
        width: 35,
        height: 35,
        borderRadius: 35,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.lighter_green,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: COLORS.white,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      input_box: {
        height: 50,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
        width: width,
      },
      back_icon_box: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 40,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      input: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.light_grey,
        borderRadius: 16,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        fontSize: 15,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
      },
      content: {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        zIndex: 999,
      },
      content_safe_area: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 80 : 40,
        paddingBottom: 80,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
      },
      content_inner: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderTopColor: COLORS.light_grey,
      },
      image_placeholder_container: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        marginTop: 100,
      },
      image_placeholder: {
        height: 80,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        alignSelf: 'center',
      },
      image_placeholder_text: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'black',
        marginTop: 5,
      },
      search_item: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        height: 40,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#e6e4eb',
        marginLeft: 16,
      },
      item_icon: {
        marginRight: 15,
      }
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Вы бы хоть ошибку получаемую текстом вписали в вопрос, вы думаете кто-то захочет ее вручную вбивать в поиск, чтоб нагуглить причины ее появления и помочь? Не удивляйтесь, что вам не могут, или не хотят помогать, какой вопрос, такой и ответ.